# Creating a an Object of an Object Angular 4

Tags: angular, typescript

I have defined an interface :

```
export interface Student {
  name : String;
  section:String;
  phoneNumber:String;
}
```

i want to create an Object of an Object of type Student with `studentId` as key . i.e

`studentDetails[studentId]` should be of type Student;

```
studentDetails[studentId] : Student = [];
```

How can i implement this using inteface ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Object of an object? can you explain that?

Comment: Question very unclear

Comment: i guess he is looking for a map operator on his object like `{id: {name:..}}`

Comment: do you mean some sort of array/map of student objects?

Comment: @Jota.Toledo thank you for the reply . i didn't know how to put it . basically i want an object which takes a key and the value is of type Student

Comment: That's just a basic javascript object {}... let obj = {}; obj[studentId] = {}; You can make this all typed if you want

Comment: oh ok, so that would be Map<number/string,Student> depending if the studentId is a string or number

Comment: @Jota.Toledo Yes

Comment: @suraj yes a map of StudentId and Student using interface

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can define another interface for `StudentDetails` like this:

```
export interface Student {
  name: string;
  section: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}

export interface StudentDetails {
  [key: number]: Student; //Or string instead of number
}
```

And use it like this:

```
//Valid
let studentDetails: StudentDetails = {
  1: {
    name: 'Test Person1',
    section: 'Section 1',
    phoneNumber: '12345678'
  }
};

//Valid
studentDetails[2] = {
  name: 'Test Person 2',
  section: 'Section 2',
  phoneNumber: '87654321'
};

//Invalid (properties in UpperCase)
studentDetails[3] = {
  Name: 'Test Person 3',
  Section: 'Section 3',
  PhoneNumber: '52376724'
};

//Valid
let student: Student = studentDetails[2];
```

**UPDATE**

From your comment to my answer, I assume you want something like this instead:

```
export interface Student {
  id: number; // Added
  name: string;
  section: string;
  phoneNumber: string;
}

export interface StudentMap {
  [key: number]: Student;
}

let studentMap: StudentMap = {};
let studentDetails: Student[] = [
  {
    id: 56,
    name: 'Test Person1',
    section: 'Section 1',
    phoneNumber: '12345678'
  },
  {
    id: 175,
    name: 'Test Person3',
    section: 'Section 3',
    phoneNumber: '521398763'
  }
];

studentDetails.forEach((s: Student) => {
  studentMap[s.id] = s;
});

for (let i = 0; i < studentDetails.length; i++) {
  console.log(studentMap[studentDetails[i].id].name); // Test Person1, Test Person 3
}
```

Comment: how can i use the above method to do something like : 
``for(let i=0; i < this.sudentDetails.length; i++){
   this.sudentMap[studentDetails[i].id].name = this.studentDetails[i].name 
}`` ?

Comment: The syntax you're mentioning is only for iterating on **arrays**. In this example `studentDetails` is an **object**. Use the following syntax to iterate on the properties of an object : `for (var prop in obj) { console.log(`obj.${prop} = ${obj[prop]}`); }`

Comment: @CruelEngine I think your question is wrong if you want to be able to do `studentDetails[i]` and not `studentDetails[studentId]`. That would indicate an `Array` instead of an `Object`. Instead `studentMap` would be the `Object` that `studentDetails` is in my answer. `studentDetails` would simply be of type `Student[]`.

Answer (score 2):

First Add a studetId to the interface :

```
export interface Student {
name : String;
section:String;
phoneNumber:String;
studentID : number;
 }
```

Then create a map of studentId with the student detail

```
  students : Student[];
  student1 : Student;

  var studentMap = new Map();

  this.students  = [
  {name : "abc", section :'A', phoneNumber : '123',studentID : 101 },
  {name : "xyz", section :'B', phoneNumber : '456',studentID : 102 },
  {name : "mno", section :'C', phoneNumber : '789',studentID : 103 },

    ];

 for (var item of this.students){
  studentMap.set (item.studentID ,item);
 }

 this.student1 = studentMap.get(101);
```

Please see this ([Plunkr I have created](https://plnkr.co/edit/Ab6rjmrmvjGEiIZc8AnC?p=preview) )